# Why can't I install different apps with the same wildcard bundle identifier on iOS?

Tags: ios, identifier

Ok I thought a wildcard bundle identifier was so that we could use it to install many apps with the same profile, instead of creating a gazillion profiles for each app.

But we cant install the different apps on the device with the same bundle identifier, so in essence we end up having to create a bundle identifier for each app anyway.

Is this correct?  Is there anything I can do to NOT create one profile for each?

Comment: What's happening when you try to install a second app? It does work if setup correctly. Each app must have a unique bundle id. It is the App Id in the portal that has the wildcard. You then use a single provisioning profile with that wildcard app id to build and sign any number of apps - each with a specific bundle id.

Comment: thanks maddy. I was confused between the app id wildcard and the apps bundle identifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apps need distinct bundle identifiers, always. The wildcard identifier concept is used with provisioning profiles, not a app's bundle identifier. You use a wildcard provisioning profile to sign an app who's distinct and specific bundle identifier can match with the provisioning profile.